# Is it right using this expression "I am there at home"?

Tags: word-choice

I realized that I use expressions like this a lot,

> I am there at home.

instead of

> I am at home.

Is it right? And if so then what is the difference between the two? The word "there" in the first expression looks redundant.

Comment: The first use is wrong or misleading. Wherever you are is *here*, not *there*. The only way that works is if you are specifically referencing a position relative to another person's perception of where you might be, but even then it would be an odd usage.

Comment: @Robusto so according to you, "are you there at the press confrence?" is also not correct?

Comment: You can ask if someone else is *there*. But from your perspective, you would always refer to where you are as *here*.

Answer (score 2):

I think your first usage is wrong and is very unlikely to be said by a native speaker. I think what you mean is *I am here at home*. This works but doesn't mean the same as *I am home* or in your case *I am at home*. *Here* emphasize more on your being at home, while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Another colloquial application for the construction *I am there at home* would be in course of giving a present tense narration of an anecdote: "So I'm there at home when this guy knocks on the door..."

Answer (score -2):

*I am there at home* is grammatically correct, but perhaps a bit awkward.  As can be seen via [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+there+at+home%2CThere+I+am+at+home%2CI+am+at+home+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) it doesn't show up in enough books to register, while the phrases *There I am at home* and *I am at home there* do appear in print.  The three phrases have similar meanings, except that *There I am at home* might also be used to set a scene, for example in sentences like *There I am at home, everything just great, when Tom shows up.*

I can imagine *I am there at home* being used for rhetorical effect in a context like *Rome! I am there at home*, where it sounds well, but doubt anyone would say *Peoria! I am there at home*, where it doesn't.

Comment: The latter more usually ordered _Peoria! I am at home there_, short for _I feel at home on the occasions when I am there_.